# Additional Twitter Bootstrap label/button/alert/badge colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a ready-to-use pack for bootstrap to add additional colors, others than the default ones ?

Default colors are (label example) :

```
<span class="label">Default</span>
<span class="label label-success">Success</span>
<span class="label label-warning">Warning</span>
<span class="label label-important">Important</span>
<span class="label label-info">Info</span>
<span class="label label-inverse">Inverse</span>
```

Answer (score 16):

you can quickly and easily set your own color set for labels, using this kind of CSS :

```
.label-default {
  background-color: #999;
}
.label-default[href]:hover,
.label-default[href]:focus {
  background-color: #808080;
}
.label-primary {
  background-color: #428bca;
}
.label-primary[href]:hover,
.label-primary[href]:focus {
  background-color: #3071a9;
}
.label-success {
  background-color: #5cb85c;
}
.label-success[href]:hover,
.label-success[href]:focus {
  background-color: #449d44;
}
.label-info {
  background-color: #5bc0de;
}
.label-info[href]:hover,
.label-info[href]:focus {
  background-color: #31b0d5;
}
.label-warning {
  background-color: #f0ad4e;
}
.label-warning[href]:hover,
.label-warning[href]:focus {
  background-color: #ec971f;
}
.label-danger {
  background-color: #d9534f;
}
.label-danger[href]:hover,
.label-danger[href]:focus {
  background-color: #c9302c;
}
```

Here are 2 sets :

[image]

- default: `#95a5a6` / `#7f8c8d`
- primary: `#3498db` / `#2980b9`
- success: `#2ecc71` / `#27ae60`
- info:    `#9b59b6` / `#8e44ad`
- warning: `#e67e22` / `#d35400`
- danger:  `#e74c3c` / `#c0392b`

[image]

- default: `#95a5a6` / `#7f8c8d`
- primary: `#00A388` / `#007D68`
- success: `#79BD8F` / `#659E78`
- info:    `#BEEB9F` / `#A5CC8A`
- warning: `#FFFF9D` / `#D1D181`
- danger:  `#FF6138` / `#D6512F`

[**Bootply example**](http://bootply.com/112988)

Comment: You have just theming of existing class, we need additional class, for more colors.

Answer (score 10):

Some 3rd party custom themes have added colors, but I'm not aware of a "ready to use pack". It's easy to add your own by just extending the CSS. For example here are "social" buttons..

**CSS**

```
.btn-facebook {
    background-color:#3b5998;
    color:#fff;
}
.btn-google {
    background-color:#dd4b39;
    color:#fff;
}
.btn-twitter {
    background-color:#2ba9e1;
    color:#fff;
}
.btn-pinterest {
    background-color:#cb2027;
    color:#fff;
}
.btn-tumblr {
    background-color:#2c4762;
    color:#fff;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<button class="btn btn-facebook btn-lg">Facebook</button>
```

***EDIT***

You could also use CSS wildcard selectors to create styles like this..

Apple colors demo: http://bootply.com/112999

Answer (score 9):

Although the OP is asking for a "ready-to-use pack", I stumbled across this while looking for something myself. [Bootstrap Button Generator](http://blog.koalite.com/bbg/) offers a dead simple online tool for quickly creating additional button colors.

Also this one, it will build out the HTML and CSS for a custom button: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-button-generator.php

Answer (score 4):

Even though zessx's answer is correct, maybe some users won't understand that the solution is valid for the creation of brand new classes, as my example below:

```
.label-alarm {
  background-color: #e0e000;
}
.label-alarm[href]:hover,
.label-alarm[href]:focus {
  background-color: #e0e12;
}
```

By adding this code, we will have a new label class called "label-alarm" besides all the standard Bootstrap classes (label-default, label-primary, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this with the bootstrap less mixins for buttons, and something like the following:

```
@import "path/to/bootstrap/mixins/buttons.less";
// Danger and error appear as red
.btn-sample {
  .button-variant(@btn-sample-color; @btn-sample-bg; @btn-sample-border);
}
```

This will save you a lot of time and potential errors over writing custom css, particularly if you want labels, buttons, panels, etc, all in your new color.

For whatever reason, I can't find information about this option on the Bootstrap website, but here is a third party guide to some of these options:
https://www.sitepoint.com/less-beyond-basics-bootstrap-mixins-library/

Answer (score 0):

The AngularJS documentation also defines a couple of custom color styles, you might want to *steal*, if you are lazy. At least it gives you an idea, how you can create your own color scheme.

**CSS**

```
.type-hint-expression {
  background: purple;
}

.type-hint-date {
  background: pink;
}

.type-hint-string {
  background: #3a87ad;
}

.type-hint-function {
  background: green;
}

.type-hint-object {
  background: #999;
}

.type-hint-array {
  background: #F90;
}

.type-hint-boolean {
  background: rgb(18, 131, 39);
}

.type-hint-number {
  background: rgb(189, 63, 66);
}

.type-hint-regexp {
  background: rgb(90, 84, 189);
}

.type-hint-domelement {
  background: rgb(95, 158, 160);
}
```

**Usage**

```
<span class="label type-hint-number">number</span>
```

**Example**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo#limitTo-arguments

**Source**

https://docs.angularjs.org/css/docs.css

PS: I do *not* endorse stealing code. Create your own, unique style, or at least reference the source, if you use someone else's code.